# How to install libraries in python without pip to make sure the integrity of their code?

Tags: python, security, pip, integrity

I am working in a company that do not permit installing libraries without cybersecurity department permission. So I had to download the libraries for example from pypi.org, send them for authorization and install them by calling setup. However, I wonder if there are better solutions/practices to guaranty the sanity of the libraries. For example, I tried to download Google ortools, and this is not as easy as it appears.

Answer (score 1):

You can package your project with the wheel (.whl) files it needs on the platform it will be running on. That way, your IT dept. can sign off on those specific binaries and allow their installation, and you can be guaranteed they will work the same every time the software is installed.

However, it does mean that your software can no longer be installed just anywhere. Picking, downloading (or building) and including specific wheels means locking yourself into a limited range of Python versions, for a specific hardware architecture.

Comment: How about just data science projects where there is no need for the installation or deployment. Just modeling, testing and version control with DVC. How about using docker images? What are the best practices for this type of problems? Also there is an issue with the security of some of the libraries. Not all packages in pip are secure. I am not sure but it must be difficult for the IT department to validate their quality. What do governments do in these cases with strict security measures and management and governance of sensitive data?

Comment: Your question doesn't have a short answer - being able to answer all of it is a career. I'm the application architect for a large consultancy that has government (including defence) as clients, so we have parts of the business that have this problem. Installation or deployment is stricly controlled, Docker isn't a part of it but could be, depending on the complexity of what you're installing - however, it makes more sense to provide access to a controlled application server instead of installing locally. Binaries and code are reviewed in detail before whitelisting, binaries will be signed.

Comment: But the comment section of a StackOverflow question is *not* where you should be looking for this advice - hire a professional, because the answer to all of your question is "it depends" and someone should really look more closely at your situation before just recommending some supposed panacea to make your problems go away.

Comment: I am lost in how to even approach the problem. it is a real problem and a question for everybody. Everybody who uses python should be scared of cybersecurity. We consulted two successful governments this answer impacts a whole nation. I think it deserves classification of "it depends" and associated solutions.How about give reference to class of problems and solutions. "It depends" is a good answer if you know at least one solution for a specific case otherwise it is not productive. Or offer some keywords to check in Scholar or books that give solutions.

Comment: Statements like "we consulted two successful governments this answer impacts a whole nation" don't inspire confidence that you're at all serious about this - you should reconsider your approach.

Answer (score 0):

can you use pip to install your downloaded and aproved libraries from a local path?... or is the use of pip prohibited?
[link to python pip documentation to do that](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#id26)

pip is the official python package manager. Paraphrasing what the  previous link say: If you installed Python from source, with an installer from python.org, or via Homebrew you should already have pip. If pip isn’t already installed you can securely download get-pip.py from the link above and run it to install and update pip. Then you can use pip to install your desired packages from the Python Package Index.
You can ckeck if you already have pip and upgrade it by running:

```
python3 -m pip --version
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

You can try letting pip download the library you want to install by running:

`python3 -m pip install "SomeLibrary"`

Or of this doesn't work because of your security blockage you can try installing yout downloaded library from the local file:

`python3 -m pip install ./downloads/SomeLibrary-1.0.4.tar.gz`

Comment: The downloading of any library directly is prohibited. They also block access to all pages that contain information to download. For example this page for downloading R language libraries is blocked: https://cran.r-project.org/
I think that local usage of pip is not subject to the restrictions.